# jQuery won't use 2 selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It won't get the 2 selector to work together it only uses the second one, I don't know how. I am new to jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div class="janee">
  <input id="JA2" type="radio" name="group3" value="Ja">
  <label for="JA2" class="form-field__radio__label">Ja, meerprijs €1.50 per m<sup>2</sup></label><br>
  <input id="NEE2" type="radio" name="group3" onclick="JaNeeFirst()" value="Nee">
  <label for="NEE2">Nee</label>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="janee">
  <input id="JA3" type="radio" name="group4" value="Ja">
  <label for="JA3" class="form-field__radio__label">Ja</label><br>
  <input id="NEE3" type="radio" name="group4" onclick="JaNeeSecond()" value="Nee">
  <label for="NEE3">Nee</label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $('#JA2') && $('#JA3').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
    {
      alert('Selected');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate them by comma

```
$('#JA2, #JA3').click(function()...
```

```js
$('#JA2, #JA3').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
  {
    alert('Selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="janee">
  <input id="JA2" type="radio" name="group3" value="Ja">
  <label for="JA2" class="form-field__radio__label">Ja, meerprijs €1.50 per m<sup>2</sup></label><br>
  <input id="NEE2" type="radio" name="group3" onclick="JaNeeFirst()" value="Nee">
  <label for="NEE2">Nee</label>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="janee">
  <input id="JA3" type="radio" name="group4" value="Ja">
  <label for="JA3" class="form-field__radio__label">Ja</label><br>
  <input id="NEE3" type="radio" name="group4" onclick="JaNeeSecond()" value="Nee">
  <label for="NEE3">Nee</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but i want it to show the alert when both are selected. Not just 1.

Comment: @Gumpy, try `if ($('#JA2').is(':checked') && $('#JA3').is(':checked'))`

Answer (score 3):

Because that's not valid JavaScript.

You can [separate selectors with a comma](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('#JA2, #JA3').click(function() { });
```

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order.

Or you can use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$('#JA2').add('#JA3').click(function() { });
```

Comment: Yes but i want it to show the alert when both are selected. Not just 1.

Comment: Then your logic is incorrect, and your question is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you have to supply a comma-separated string if you want to select multiple elements. You can refer to their documentation here https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/#post-435

For example:

```
$('#element-one, #element-two').css('border', '3px solid red');
```

The above will add a red border to elements with an id of 'element-one' and 'element-two'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#JA2, #JA3').click(function() {
   if ($('#JA2').prop('checked') && $('#JA3').prop('checked')) {
       alert('Both checked');
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello. While this code may answer the question, it is better to include an explanation to your code. Code-only answers can be difficult to understand without any explanation.